# Restart a new subprocess multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module to run tasks. If one of the processes is stopped because of some exception, can I start a new one to replace it and then make sure that the total number of processes is not changed.

If I use code below, one process will stop because of the int<>float conversion error, then only one process is actually running. Thanks a lot.

```
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty
import time
import os

def multi_processing():
    print("main_process:", os.getpid())

    items = ["1", "0.1", "2", "5", "6"]

    tasks_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    for item in items:
        tasks_queue.put(item)

    number_of_procs = 2
    process_list = list()

    for _ in range(number_of_procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=tasks_from_queue, args=(tasks_queue,)
        )
        process_list.append(process)
        process.start() 

    for process in process_list:
        process.join()

    print("Finished task")


def tasks_from_queue(tasks_queue,):
    """
    Get tasks to process form queue
    """
    while not tasks_queue.empty():
        try:
            item = tasks_queue.get(block=True, timeout=2)
        except Empty:
            print("Tasks queue empty")
            break

        time.sleep(5)
        print("sub_process", os.getpid(), "get_item", int(item))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi_processing()
```

Comment: I think you would need to send a signal from the faulty process to the main program if there is an exception. The main would have to wait for it in an infinite loop, and break only if all threads terminated properly. In case of exception, it would have to restart the faulty process.

Comment: Where do you think I can add that to send a signal to the main exception? Try catch in the for loop? How too keep the infinite loop? Thanks.